# iOS autolayout with constraints. Some of TableViewCell is showing off screen

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I am having issues with `AutoLayout` in `XCode 6.1`.

I am trying to achieve a Card-style looking `TableView` and so I created a `Prototype Cell` with a gray background and a `View` inside to simulate the card.

I then added the following constraints to the `View`:

- trailing space
- leading space
- bottom space
- top space
- width
- height
- align center vertically
- align center horizontally

And now I can't understand why some of the white `View` is being shown off screen to the right.

You can see what it looks like in the iOS simulator below as well as the prototype cell.

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: by adding width and height constraints you have given a definite size to the cell. I would recommend that you try removing all those constraints and just let xcode add required constraints automatically from the menu in the bottom right corner of xcode

Comment: You can remove the width and height constraint. As @jordan suggested, you just need to use the leading, trailing, top and bottom.

Answer (score 2):

As Krishna suggested, pinning the width and height will override the trailing/leading and top/bottom constraints.
To make a view size according to the superview/cell, you just have to pin trailing, leading, top and bottom with some constants if you need to add padding.
Remove the width and height constraints and it would work just fine

Answer (score 1):

You have too many constraints and as Krishna alluded to I suspect that it is the Width constraint that is causing the issue.

Remove the width constraint as this will be handled by the trailing and leading constraints.

Below is a screenshot including a Preview and the constraints used on the UIView:

[image: Screenshot of IB]

Answer (score 0):

It was my fault! I didn't set the constraints for the `TableView` so the it was showing offscreen.

Stupid mistake!